# what is possible way to use the function from the other file, which was initialized by a static?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

My question is simple.

I have three files in my program.suppose one of files has static function.how can I use that function from the other one?

I knew that static function accessed by the files itself.i want to know any possible way.

If the way is available, how can i stop that access in terms of function declaration?

Comment: Change them to not be defined `static` anynmore? Or add a wrapper to this static function which itself isn't static?

Comment: The module itself can always pass on a pointer to it. And if you're truly insane you can parse the map file/debug information to hunt it out. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If the symbol/debug table is available in the binary, you could read it and calculate a function pointer to it. What level of "no access" are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

A function declared as file-scope static will not be visible from outside the file, meaning that you will not be able to look the function up by name etc. However, if a function from the same file hands out a pointer to the function, code will be able to call it, since there is no resolving or lookup involved.