# How to call a static function

Tags: c

I'm trying to call the following function

In daydream.c :

```
.....
static int create_new_account(void)
{
    DDPut(sd[newucstr]);
    switch (HotKey(HOT_NOYES)) {
    case 1:
            if (CreateNewAccount()) {
                    clog.cl_userid = user.user_account_id;
                    clog.cl_firstcall = user.user_firstcall;
                    clog.cl_logon = time(0);
                    if (user.user_connections == 0)
                            clog.cl_flags |= CL_NEWUSER;
                    clog.cl_bpsrate = bpsrate;

                    getin();
                    return 1;
            }
            return 0;
    case 2:
            DDPut("\n");
            return 0;
    default:
            return 1;
    }
}
```

From matrix.c:

```
int apply()
{
create_new_account();
}
```

However, it won't compile link:

```
matrix.o: In function `apply':
matrix.c:(.text+0xf0): undefined reference to `create_new_account'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [daydream] Error 1
```

So, my question is, how do I call this function properly?

Comment: Remove the `static`.

Comment: And add a prototype declaration of the function to the header for `daydream.c` (presumably `saydream.h`) and make sure the `matrix.c` includes the header.  Note that the declaration should be `extern int create_new_account(void);` (where the `extern` is optional but the `void` is not because this is C and not C++).

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is possible way to use the function from the other file, which was initialized by a static?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812996/what-is-possible-way-to-use-the-function-from-the-other-file-which-was-initiali)

Answer (score 4):

You must not know what the keyword `static` means.  `static` keeps `create_new_account` global to `daydream.c` only.  Nobody else can access it.  If you want other functions to access it:

1. Remove the keyword `static` and `extern` this function into `matrix.c`.

   > Option 1:

   ```
   /* daydream.c */
   int create_new_account(void)
   {
       ...
   }

   /* matrix.c */
   extern create_new_account(void);
   ```

   > Option 2:

   ```
   /* daydream.c */
   int create_new_account(void)
   {
       ....
   }

   /* daydream.h */
   extern int create_new_account(void);

   /* matrix.c */
   #include "daydream.h"
   ```
2. Create a external wrapper function to call that in turn calls your `static` function.

   ```
   /* daydream.c */

   static int create_new_account(void)
   {
       ...
   }

   int create_new_account_wrapper(void)
   {
       return create_new_account();
   }

   /* matrix.c */
   int apply(void)
   {
       return create_new_account_wrapper();
   }
   ```

My preference is answer 1, option 2.

Comment: Indeed "static" takes on different meanings when used on local variables vs function declarations, vs inline functions. The OP needs to read up on the meaning of this keyword, in C.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it, but it isn't accepting your code for some reason. When I try to connect, I get a "connection closed by foreign host".

Comment: This is all for a BBS, BTW.

Comment: @user2990606 That's another issue, unrelated to what we've discussed in this question.

Comment: I know I, just thought I would specify.